# How can I use LINQ to see if a list<string> contains a string that starts with 'blah'?

Tags: c#, generics, list

I have a List with a few strings in it. I want to see if it contains a a string that starts with 'blah' however, I'm not sure how to use the (this IEnumerable source, value):bool overload of List.Contains.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: 3.5, I'm going to accept your answer as soon as SO lets me. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [**`List.Exists`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca.aspx):

```
bool result = list.Exists(x => x.StartsWith("blah"));
```

Or [**`Enumerable.Any`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972.aspx) then it works with other collection types too:

```
bool result = list.Any(x => x.StartsWith("blah"));
```